# how to get the json from array in ios

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have an array contain string and json has objects, from the array I need to get only the json. How to get the json from array? I have shown the array below:

```
array (
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "sda@sdas.com",
    "[{  \"field_value\" : \"\\/Users\\/poornima\\/Library\\/Application Support\\/iPhone Simulator\\/5.1\\/Applications\\/BCA9D949-D85D-4CA7-B753-7315C0383137\\/Documents\\/EGOoTtqT4e.png\",  \"field_name\" : \"Photo\"},{  \"field_value\" : \"\",  \"field_name\" : \"Signature\"},{  \"field_value\" : \"\",  \"field_name\" : \"File Upload\"}]",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "37.785834",
    "-122.406417",
    "2013-02-01 05:44:01",
    "superadmin@gmail.com",
    ""
)
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Uh, reference the array element?  (JSON is a string, remember.)  If you want the object representation of the JSON, send it through a JSON parser.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Or did you not know how to read the Apple NSArray doc to find out how to extract an array element?

Answer (score 0):

look like this ..

```
NSString *jsonString = @"your json";
NSData *JSONdata = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *jsonError = nil;
if (JSONdata != nil) {
    //this you need to know json root is NSDictionary or NSArray , you smaple is NSDictionary
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONdata options:0 error:&jsonError];
    if (jsonError == nil) {
        //every need check value is null or not , json null like ( "count": null )
        if (dic == (NSDictionary *)[NSNull null]) {
            return nil;
        }

        //every property you must know , what type is

        if ([dic objectForKey:@"count"] != [NSNull null]) {
            [self setCount:[[dic objectForKey:@"count"] integerValue]];
        }
        if ([dic objectForKey:@"item"] != [NSNull null]) {
            NSArray *itemArray = [dic objectForKey:@"item"]; // check null if need
            for (NSDictionary *itemDic in itemArray){
                NSString *_id = [dic objectForKey:@"id"]; // check null if need
                NSNumber *found = (NSNumber *)[dic objectForKey:@"found"];
                //.....
                //.... just Dictionary get key value
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do :

for(NSString *string in arrayName) 
{
NSDictionary *dicReturn = [string JSONValue];
         if(dicReturn !=nil){
          `NSString * fieldvalue =[dicReturn objectForKey:@"field_value"];
          NSString *fileName =[dicReturn objectForKey:@"field_name"];
}`
}